# Android using BitmapFactory decodeStream to decode mpeg h264 video from socket

Tags: android, sockets

i'm trying to stream h.264 video across the lan from my pc to android.

i wrote a simple server at accepts a connection for android, reads a test file from here
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425 sample_iPod.m4v and does a series of sends with a bit of a wait in the loop so i don't flod the network

here the server thread

```
int CLmfdtServerThread::Run()
{
    TRACE("CLPitServerThread::Run START\n") ;
    int sz = 2236480;
    char* testbits = new char[sz];
    FILE* fp = fopen("d:/misc/sample_iPod.m4v", "rb");
    int n = fread(testbits, 1, sz, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    SOCKET serverSocket=NULL;


        for( ; ; Sleep(1000) ) {            // try to connect to android ever 1 secs

            // open a server socket to listen for connections from androids
            strcpy(g_androidLmfdMsg, "Not connected"); g_theDialog->Invalidate();

            SOCKET clientSocket = socketSetupAndWaitAccept(serverSocket, 21121, g_androidLmfdMsg);
            if(!clientSocket)
                continue;   

            for( int i=0 ; i<sz; i+=10000 ) {
                TRACE("CLPitServerThread::Run try send lmfd\n");
                int bytesSent = send(clientSocket, (char*)testbits, 10000, 0);
                if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR || bytesSent!=10000) {
                    int erno = WSAGetLastError(); closesocket(clientSocket); WSACleanup(); 
                    break;
                }
                TRACE("CLPitServerThread::Run sent lmfd %d bytes\n", bytesSent);
                Sleep(20);
            }
    }
```

on android i create an async task

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        mMfdImg = (ImageView) MainActivity.getStaticRef().findViewById(R.id.imageViewMfd);


        while(true) {

            try {

                if(mServerIP==null) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    continue;
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Socket socket = new Socket(mServerIP, LPIT_PORT);   // LMFD port is 21121    

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());                 

                for ( mLoops=0 ; ; mLoops++ ) { //                       
                    mMfdBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(dis);
                    publishProgress();              // force redraw
                    Thread.sleep(5);                // 
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();            
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        
        }
    }
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        //Log.d("ReadAndDisplay", "onProgressUpdate");

        mMfdImg.setImageBitmap(mMfdBmp);        // draw new img to screen
        mMfdImg.invalidate();
```

but it doesn't work, decodeStream immediately returns NULL
it should decode h.264 according to this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

i have a similar system working now that sends jpegs from the server, then i do a readFully on the socket and use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray and that works fine, but i'd like to mode from jpegs to mpegs to save bandwidth

any ideas anyone? thanks

UPDATE

to simplify things i copied the file to the sdcard (another test file, sure its h.264 baseline video only) and verified it plays on videoplayer

then i wrote this

```
final String fname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/out.mp4";
                    try {

                        File file = new File(fname);
                        byte[] ip = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        fis.read(ip);
                        fis.close();

                        mMfdBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (ip, 0, ip.length);
                        publishProgress();              // force redraw

                    } catch
```

i verified the stuff in ip is real mp4 data. still no luck, and i tried decodeFile too, same result.

i use exactly the same code but load a .jpp and it works fine

i guess this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core is lying when it says 
H.264 AVC   •
(Android 3.0+)  •   Baseline Profile (BP)   • 3GPP (.3gp)
• MPEG-4 (.mp4)

Comment: If you want a bitmap, look into the image section. The other formats are in the video section.

Comment: bitmap not necessary, it can be a surface or a surface view, i don't care so lond as i can get it on the screen